# moving bones messes with the mesh

Tags: rigging

When I move the bones, the mesh gets affected weirdly and I don't know what to do. I have checked that the weight painting is done correctly.
[image]

Comment: that certainly looks like a weight painting issue.  Can you add your blend file to your question?

Comment: I am new to blender stack exchange, how would I attach a file?

Comment: Grab the URL of the question


Go to https://blend-exchange.com/

Select the blend file

Add the url of the question

Grab the url that results

Go back to the question and edit it

Add the new url to the bottom of the post

Comment: blend exchange doesn't seem to be working for me is there any other way?

Comment: Just simple weight painting problem. I suggest you to see a tutorial-video on youtube or so

Comment: I already have, and I have checked that all the weight painting is done correctly.